# Next.js Fetching Json to Display in Components

Tags: reactjs, json, next.js, components

I'm trying to take the function MainMenu and getStaticProps from being in the same page (index.js) and break it up into components. Here is the index.js page below that is working good.

```
#index.js

import Link from 'next/link';

function MainMenu({ menuLists }) {
  return (
   <div>
      {menuLists.map(menuItem => (
        <div>
          <Link href={menuItem.absolute}><a>{menuItem.title}</a></Link>

          {menuItem.below && menuItem.below.map(childItem => (
            <div>
              <Link href={childItem.absolute}><a>{childItem.title}</a></Link>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      ))}
  </div>
  )
}
export async function getStaticProps() {

  const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8888/api/menu_items/main');
  const menuLists = await response.json();
  
  return {
    props: {
      menuLists: menuLists,
    },
  }
}
export default MainMenu
```

I have created fetch-mainmenu.js in a lib directory with the following code.

```
#fetch-mainmenu.js

export async function loadMainMenu() {
    
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8888/api/menu_items/main')
    const menuLists = await response.json()
  
    return {
        props: {
          menuLists: menuLists,
        },
      }
  }
```

I then created sidebar.js to show the menu system from the json file. The sidebar.js file is working because the hard coded menus are showing.

```
# sidebar.js

import Link from 'next/link'
import styles from './sidebar.module.css'
import { loadMainMenu } from '../lib/fetch-mainmenu'

export default function Sidebar( { menuLists } ) {

const menus = loadMainMenu()

  return (
  
    <nav className={styles.nav}>
      <input className={styles.input} placeholder="Search..." />
      <Link href="/">
        
        <a>Home</a>
      </Link>
      <Link href="/about">
        <a>About</a>
      </Link>
      <Link href="/contact">
        <a>Contact</a>
      </Link>
    </nav>
  )
}
```

Getting the following error "TypeError: Failed to fetch".
What is the best way of getting this done using components.

Comment: In React, side-effects like fetching data should be done inside a [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook. Move the `loadMainMenu` function call inside a `useEffect`.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

### 1. Prop Drilling

Easy. Just send down all the data from `getStaticProps()`. This is the safest bet at current stage but it may create some redundant props.

```js
// I've omitted fetch().json() to ease the reading. just assume it's a proper code.

const MainMenuComponent = ({menuLists}) => {
  return <div>{menuLists}</div>
}

const MainPage = ({menuLists}) => {
  return <MainMenuComponent menuLists={menuLists} />
}

export async function getStaticProps() {

  const req = await fetch('...');
  
  return {
    props: {
      menuLists: req,
    },
  }
}
export default MainPage
```

### 2. React.useEffect

A React component can't have asynchronous code inside render code. It is pretty obvious in a class component but it's hard to tell in a functional component

```js
// I've omitted fetch().json() to ease the reading. just assume it's a proper code.

// class component
class SampleComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { data: {} };
  }
  async getData() {
    // ✅ this works
    const data = await fetch('...');
    // data has to be put in state because it's asynchronous.
    this.setState({ ...this.state, data });
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getData();
  }
  render() {
    // ❌ this can't happen here because render is synchronous
    await fetch('...');
    // use state to display asynchronous data.
    return <h1>Hello, {JSON.stringify(this.state.data)}</h1>;
  }
}


// functional component
function SampleComponent = () => {
  // everything outside `useEffect, useLayoutEffect` is mostly assumed as render function.
  // ❌ thus, this does not work here
  await fetch('...');

  const [data, setData] = useState({});
  useEffect(async () => {
    // everything inside here treated as componentDidMount()
    // not the exact same thing though.
    // ✅ this works!
    setData(await fetch('...'))
  }, []);

  return <h1>Hello, {JSON.stringify(data)}</h1>
}
```

**WARNING** if there's `getStaticProps` inside your page, it means the component also has to be synchronous. If the rendered component changes its content in a very short time, in a fraction of second, then it may get rehydration error. It needs to be wrapped with `dynamic()` so that the Next.js can ignore the component when rendering server-side & rehydrating the component. Please refer to [Next.js official document on Dynamic Import](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import).

It does work but the code seems long.

### 3. TanStack Query(or React-Query) or useSWR

There are nice 3rd party libraries that help writing asynchronous data fetching code inside a react component; [TanStack Query](https://tanstack.com/query/v4) and [SWR](https://swr.vercel.app/) are the most well known. These libraries also implement caching and revalidation. It can help handling complex issues invoked due to asynchronous requests.

```js
// example code from useSWR
import useSWR from 'swr'

function Profile() {
  const { data, error } = useSWR('/api/user', fetcher)

  if (error) return <div>failed to load</div>
  if (!data) return <div>loading...</div>
  return <div>hello {data.name}!</div>
}
```

### 4. State Management with Context

Most cases are easily dealt with the **Query-SWR** solution but if the app gets big enough, there could be a need to synchronize the data.

In that case, fetch the data in server code and share the data with a central state management library(a.k.a store libs). A good example is [this github repo of Zustand + Next.js](https://github.com/kennethnwc/nextjs-with-zustand-typescript). A bare React.Context can be used as well.

However, this method can get very complicated later, maybe not suitable for an inexperienced team; it's basically similar to building another complex layer as big as backend. That's why the trend has moved to **Query-SWR** solution these days. Still, this comes handy in certain cases.

```js
import { useStore } from "../lib/store";
const SampleComponent = () => {
  const { data } = useStore();
  return <div>{JSON.stringify(data)}</div>
}

const MainPage() {
  return <SampleComponent />
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
  // refer to the github repo for this store structure
  const zustandStore = initializeStore();
  // this is a POC. the actual code could be different.
  // store data is updated, and can be used globally in other components in a synchronized state.
  const data = await useStore.setData(await fetch('...'));

  return {
    props: {
      initialZustandState: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({ ...zustandStore.getState(), data })),
    },
  };
}
```

### 5. Server-side Component

With the emergence of [React 18 server side component](https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/12/21/data-fetching-with-react-server-components.html), Next.js is also working on [Next.js Server Components](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/react-18/server-components).

This implementation is probably the closest implementation to code from the question. Nevertheless, the work is still in progress and highly unstable.

I've kept my eyes on this method for about a year but the implementation has been constantly changing. Until we get the stable release, this can wait.